# Solana Program Test with installed geyser plugin

Tags: solana-test-validator, geyser, solana-program-test

For the program I'm writing I need to "fast forward" the validator clock for some of my tests. I noticed that `warp_slot` is available in `solana-program-test` however I can't seem to find or figure out how to load a geyser plugin into the `solana-program-test` that I'll be using with my Rust tests. From my first dive into the source code, it seems like I should be able to simply load a `geyser-plugin-config` and I'd be off to the races.

Comment: `solana-program-test` doesn't support geyser unfortunately, since it only sets up the `BankForks`, and not much else required by geyser. PRs are always welcome though!